# UITableview scroll top then do and action method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I don't know if this is possible. I have `UITableview` when the user click one cell or row, the `tableview` will automatically scroll to top then do an action method after it reach at the top.

**Here's my code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; // scroll to top
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self connectToSubMenu:indexPath.row];
            }];
}
```

I don't know if I miss anything here. Sorry I'm still learning `objective-c`.

Comment: [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; because of this it will always executed at top.

Comment: what results do you see when you try this code that you have written so far?

Comment: also see docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html, there's a method `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` which seems more what you want than `setContentOffset`

Comment: @RobP the result is when you i click one row, it will scroll to top and the same time the method connectToSubMenu animate also. I want to animate the scrolltotop first before it animate the connectToSubMenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were pretty close. Using UIView's animateWithDuration is good, just need to use the right method to scroll the table position.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self connectToSubMenu:indexPath.row];    
    }];
}
```

Note also that I set animated:NO in the inner method call, since the outer method is doing the animating.

Comment: [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO]; this code doesn't work on me but i use this [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]. I set the animate to NO. now it's working. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this to set your tableview to scroll top automatically.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Your custom code
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    // Call your custom method here, Now tableview scrolled to top
}
```

Comment: I don't think this waits for the scrolling animation to complete before running the next line of code, actually.

Comment: I did this code already. Sorry I update my post. I add this in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method already.